# Looping to decode multiple JWT tokens in one call

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

We have an in-house API service that, when called with an email and password, checks for the user and sends back several JWTs (JSON web tokens).

I currently have my modified login function in the main laravel AuthController that sends the data from my login form to the API call, and upon submission, I've dumped the 4 tokens.

Dumped Tokens:

```
{#719 ▼
  +"access": "...token..."
  +"check": "...token..."
  +"permission": "...token..."
  +"secondary": "...token..."
}
```

The problem is, after integrating `use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;` and trying to dump the decoded version of my Tokens like so:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $key = "publicKey";

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $authService = new AuthService();
    $login = $authService->loginGetToken($email, $password);

    $decoded = JWT::decode($login, $key, array('HS256'));
    dd($decoded);

    return redirect(route('auth.login'))
        ->with('login', $login);
}
```

I get an error about wrong number of segments.

Now, if I copy any one of the tokens into the $login variable then it dumps decoded just fine, so it's obviously because I have multiple tokens in one call.

How can I decode all 4 of these JWTs properly so that I can cache them and access their info? Is there a way to loop or iterate these?

Comment: what about decoding each of them using `foreach` then recreate the object?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din how would I recreate it though?

Comment: First, please post the code that works. And please tell me How are you going to cache the decoded tokens? What do youwant to do with them?

Comment: The code above works if I dump $login (I get the 4 tokens) but when I dump $decoded it doesn't. That's why i figured I could loop on $login and decode within the loop. I plan on caching them in the session though

Comment: So $login as it is now dumps the structure I pasted above. But also, if I paste one of those 4 tokens in then it dumps the decoded version

Comment: what about `$result = []; foreach($login as $k => $v) { $result[$k] = JWT::decode($v, $key, array('HS256')); } dd($result);`?

Comment: so does it work?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din it still says wrong number of segments, for some reason. The format when I dump $login is ```{#719 ▼
  +"tokenOne": "..."
  +"tokenTwo": "..."
  +"tokenThree": "..."
  +"tokenFour": "..."
}```

Comment: And if I copy any one of the tokens and put it into the variable, it decodes fine

Comment: Also, if I do $tokenOne = $login['tokenOne']; and try to dump that I get that I can't use type stdObject class as array

Comment: why do you not decode each key alone???

Comment: I'm actually attempting that now, but it seems like 2 of them are decoding and the other 2 are not.

Comment: the JWT library expects $key to be a private, not a public key.