# Decode multiple JWT tokens from API call

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, jwt

If I dump my `$login` variable, I get all 4 tokens in the object:

```
{#719 ▼
  +"initial_access": "...token..."
  +"refresh_token": "...token..."
  +"ui_access": "...token..."
  +"auth_access": "...token..."
}
```

But I can't loop on them, and I'm even having issues dumping each one individually.

If I go one by one and comment the 4 decoding lines out, dumping them respectively, the interfaceResult and initialResult seem to dump the decoded values. However, `$refreshResult` gives me wrong number of segments error and `$authResult` says algorithm not allowed?

is there a better way to go about this so that I can decode and cache all 4 tokens?

```
    //Rest call to get tokens returned
    $login = $authService->loginGetToken($email, $password);

    //This dumps the whole object with all 4 encoded tokens
    //dd($login)

    //public key for JWT
    $key = "publicKey";

    $initial = $login->initial_access;
    $refresh = $login->refresh_token;
    $interface = $login->ui_access;
    $auth = $login->auth_access;


    $initialResult = JWT::decode($initial, $key, array('HS256')); 
    $refreshResult = JWT::decode($refresh, $key, array('HS256')); 
    $interfaceResult = JWT::decode($interface, $key, array('HS256')); 
    $authResult = JWT::decode($auth, $key, array('HS256')); 

    //dd($initialResult);
    //dd($refreshResult);
    //dd($interfaceResult);
    //dd($authResult);
```

Comment: Are you sure all these tokens are JWT ones? Could you please copy/paste a sample?

Comment: And why would you decode all those tokens?

Comment: Without knowing what "$authService" is or does: you need the private key to decode/verify the JWT token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping to decode multiple JWT tokens in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905239/looping-to-decode-multiple-jwt-tokens-in-one-call)